# How to delete MS LUIS account and create again with same account

Tags: c#, azure, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

I have created LUIS account, but wish to delete or change the subscription/pricing to standard, which now is free trail.

How to  create with same account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Navigate to **Azure Portal -> Select your resource -> Pricing Tier -> Change it to Standard**

[image]